# What does it mean when a resident says "At least there's shopping around here"?

Tags: simcity-2013

I have a few medium residential buildings that are unhappy.

What makes me happy: "At least there's shopping around here".

What makes me unhappy: Nothing listed.

Has anyone determined what this means?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to the site Kauldric! I'm a little unclear what you're asking. Do you want to know what "At least there's shopping around here" means, or are you wondering why your citizens are unhappy?

Comment: I would think from that comment that they're unhappy with the city in general and their quality of life, so much so that shopping is their only escape from the suffering that is daily life. Oh what a monotonous life a sim must live... :P

Comment: @Wipqozn Thanks for answering!  What I am wondering is why is this particular sim unhappy yet only reports reason for being happy.  What to do to make him happy seems unclear. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this before, and it is a matter of cycling through all your data views to find out exactly what the problem is. The most common culprits I have found are **crime and illness.**

When I first encountered this problem, I looked at my happiness view, and I saw this red and unhappy building in a sea of green and happy buildings. It also had the status of "At least there is shopping around here" without any things making them unhappy listed.

Come to find out after opening the crime data view, there was a really really tall column of red located in just this one building, with many criminals hanging out in there. My solution was to bulldoze the building, and let it be created anew. This forces the criminals out (it did not delete them, they just scattered) which allowed some of my police to pick them up, or for them to at least not concentrate in one place.

The same thing can happen with disease, an entire building can essentially become a quarantine zone, and you are best off bulldozing it for now.

Comment: Haha I like that. "How do you like your place? You don't? Well then..." _demolish_.

Comment: @Jeff- Kind of the way I feel about it. "Oh, you mean you're unhappy even though all your neighbors are totally content? Well then... SKADOOOOSH!!"